# Limit a 360 jQuery wheel to 300

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation

I have a 360 degrees rotating wheel on my player page which acts as a volume button eventually.

I need to limit its functionality to 270 degrees and not 360 (from 7 O'clock to 5 O'clock) so it can have the effect of min to max.

How can i achieve this using the code attached?

[The Player Page](http://www.tranceil.fm/player2)

```
         $('#metal .indicator-cw').bind('touchmove', function(event){
        updateMetal();
    });
    $("#metal .indicator-cw").mousemove(updateMetal);

    function updateMetal(){
var number = $("#metal .result-cw").text();
var Degrees = parseInt(number);
var vol = ((Degrees + 150) % 360) * (1/270);    
$musicPlayer.jPlayer("volume", vol);

$("#rotateit").css({'transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-webkit-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-o-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-moz-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)', '-ms-transform':'rotate(' + (Degrees) + 'deg)' });
    if (Degrees > 120 || Degrees < 210) return;
    }
    //js code for the metal style wheel - above
```

Comment: can you simply to a test one you have the Degrees value and if it's outside the range you want skip the rest of the function and not rotate the wheel?

Comment: 7' to 5' is 270 degrees.  My answer reflects the 7' to 5'.  You can change it to 135 and 205 if you want to make it a true 300 range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to stop updating the volume wheel

```
if (Degrees > 150 && Degrees < 210) return;
```

You'll also need to calculate the volume a bit differently

```
//This shifts the degrees from 210-120 to be 0-270 and then scales it to 0-1
var vol = ((Degrees + 150) % 360) * (1/300);
```

Comment: The volume works as 270 indeed, but the wheel keeps spinning, i updated the code above

Comment: Put the if statement before the `var vol` line

Comment: still rotate :(  function updateMetal(){
        if (Degrees > 120 || Degrees < 210) return;
 var number = $("#metal .result-cw").text();

Comment: sorry I meant && not ||.  Also the site you linked uses a library controlwheel.  That library probably has option so you don't need these hacks.  If you don't mind hard coding it you can put `if (Degrees > 120 && Degrees < 210) return;` on line 69 of `controlwheel.js` on your site.

Comment: uhhh thank you, now it works, though its not quite 5 O'clock :) more like 7 to 3:30..any thoughts?

Comment: Oops, use 150 instead of 120... and 300 instead of 270... I'm full of fail today

Comment: Right now the music is muted when hovering over the wheel how can i avoid that?